# Linebreaks do not occur - PHP to CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have a script that copys results from a table and saves it in a csv format. Everything is running fine with the script except that it does not recognize \n and just inputs it in the last cell like blahblah\r\n.

I have these lines currently but neither situation is creating the new line...-

```
$csv_output .= "$lastName,$firstName,$agentMLSID,$agentBoard,$directOffice,$directOfficeExtension,$voicemail,$mobile,$email,$officeName ".PHP_EOL;


$csv_hdr = "lastname,firstname,mslid,board,directline,ext,vm,mobile,email,office";
$csv_hdr .= "\n";
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure newlines are not supported on CSV.

Comment: @Truth It should be supported if quoted ;)

Comment: Then how do you get data to go into a new row.. if they arent supported?

Comment: There's no reason for data to go in a new row. CSV is just as it suggests, Comma Separated Values, not "Comma Seperated Values With Linebreaks".

Comment: I mean, I know it is supported because I have a similar script where the situation DOES work. The issue is I am not able to replicate it in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fputcsv()` is what you need.

```
<?php

$list = array (
   array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
   array('123', '456', '789')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
   fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Output (file.csv):

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123,456,789
```

Comment: This is an acceptable answer, though I ended up going through a different process. Instead of an array, I generated Numbered variables and loaded the results through a loop. Thank you though!